# Select2 with JSON data serialized from Django

Tags: javascript, json, django, jquery-select2-4

I have data in JSON created by Django serialization.
I use the example:
[Select2 Loading remote data](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) but still I getting information in a field that nothing found.

[image]

What should change to select2 work with data generated by Django?

JSON Data:

```
[{
    "fields": {
        "sku": "8"
    },
    "model": "catalog.product",
    "pk": 8
},{
    "fields": {
        "sku": "9"
    },
    "model": "catalog.product",
    "pk": 9
}]
```

Html:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax"><option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
  ajax: {
  url: "{% url 'catalog.views.product_sku_json' %}",
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250,
  data: function (params) {
    return {
      q: params.term, // search term
      page: params.page
    };
  },
  processResults: function (data, params) {
    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
    // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
    // scrolling can be used
    params.page = params.page || 1;

  return {
    results: data.items,
    pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
    }
  };
},
  cache: true
},
escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by kevin-brown on github:

You are going to need to re-map your results to have id and text keys.

https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id

And it works thanks Kevin!

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore but this one is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571454/1526703